# How to save a variable inside a shader on WebGL, and how to read its value from the JavaScript program?

Tags: javascript, browser, opengl-es, webgl

I'm trying to use textures on WebGL to perform parallel array folding operations. The problem is I don't know how to save the result of a computation performed on the shader on the GPU itself. I also don't know how to read it back from JavaScript when the computation is done. See below for illustration:

```
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 pix_pos; // the 2D coord of the texture
uniform sampler2D texture; // this is the input array
    uniform sum_step(uniform* sampler2D){
       // this should perform a reduction step
       // for example, if texture = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
       // then, in the next step, it would be:
       // [3,7,11,15]
       // and so on, until we get the sum in O(log(n))
    };
void main(void) {
    if (texture.length > 1) // if not fully processed, computes a step
        texture = sum_step(texture); // don't work, texture is readonly!
};
```

Comment: you could write the values to an offscreen framebuffer and then use that result

Answer (score 3):

The GPU writes pixels. **Those pixels ARE THE SAVED DATA**.

For example [this article](http://games.greggman.com/game/webgl-image-processing/) shows how to read 9 pixels of data, multiple each by a constant, divide them by a number and then write a pixel with a shader that looks like this

```
precision mediump float;

// our texture
uniform sampler2D u_image;
uniform vec2 u_textureSize;
uniform float u_kernel[9];

// the texCoords passed in from the vertex shader.
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {
   vec2 onePixel = vec2(1.0, 1.0) / u_textureSize;
   vec4 colorSum =
     texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord + onePixel * vec2(-1, -1)) * u_kernel[0] +
     texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord + onePixel * vec2( 0, -1)) * u_kernel[1] +
     texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord + onePixel * vec2( 1, -1)) * u_kernel[2] +
     texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord + onePixel * vec2(-1,  0)) * u_kernel[3] +
     texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord + onePixel * vec2( 0,  0)) * u_kernel[4] +
     texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord + onePixel * vec2( 1,  0)) * u_kernel[5] +
     texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord + onePixel * vec2(-1,  1)) * u_kernel[6] +
     texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord + onePixel * vec2( 0,  1)) * u_kernel[7] +
     texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord + onePixel * vec2( 1,  1)) * u_kernel[8] ;
   float kernelWeight =
     u_kernel[0] +
     u_kernel[1] +
     u_kernel[2] +
     u_kernel[3] +
     u_kernel[4] +
     u_kernel[5] +
     u_kernel[6] +
     u_kernel[7] +
     u_kernel[8] ;

   if (kernelWeight <= 0.0) {
     kernelWeight = 1.0;
   }

   // Divide the sum by the weight but just use rgb
   // we'll set alpha to 1.0
   gl_FragColor = vec4((colorSum / kernelWeight).rgb, 1.0);
}
```

To read the data back you call `gl.readPixels`.

When writing your pixels you can either write them to the canvas, the default, or you can make a texture, attach it to a framebuffer and write to (by drawing) and read from (by calling gl.readPixels) the framebuffer's texture.

That sample linked above only uses `RGBA`/`UNSIGNED_BYTE` textures which are 8 bits per channel, 4 channels. You can also use `RGBA`/`FLOAT` textures if the user's hardware supports it by enabling the `OES_texture_float` extension.

The only complication is, in WebGL (1.0), you can't read floats using `gl.readPixels`. Only bytes are allowed. But, once you have your data in a FLOAT texture you could then draw that texture into an `RGBA`/`UNSIGNED_BYTE` texture and split the float data into 4 bytes and then read it back out as bytes (using `gl.readPixels`) and assemble it back into floats in JavaScript

PS: Yes I know that linking to code is *bad* but the question itself is answered. (you save data by drawing pixels and read data by calling `gl.readPixels`) The link is only there as an example.